# Horizontally aligning molecules

Tags: chemfig

I'm trying to get the plus signs in both reactions to line up with the arrow and other plus sign in the equation. I've tried rearranging the \arrow{0}[,0] around to see if that changes anything, though I've been stuck for abit now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep = ^ 4mm _ 4mm % border gap
\begin{tabu} to 13cm {|X[cm]|}
    \hline
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]O-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75]-[:-30,0.75]OH}
    \arrow[,1.1,thick]
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]O-[:30,0.75]-[:-30,0.75]}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+ 
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]OH}
    \schemestop
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}

\vspace{2mm}
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep = ^ 4mm _ 4mm % border gap
\begin{tabu} to 13cm {|X[cm]|}
    \hline
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]OH}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]OH}
    \arrow[,1.5,thick]
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30]O-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+ 
    \chemfig{H_2O}
    \schemestop
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you may nevertheless want to avoid the use of `tabu` as this package is unmaintained and buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is how the molecules were written

```
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep = ^ 4mm _ 4mm % border gap
\begin{tabu} to 16cm {|X[cm]|}
    \hline
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{(-[:210])(=[2]O)-[:330]O-[:30](=[2]O)-[:330]}
%
\+
%
\chemfig{-[:30]-[:330]OH}
%
\arrow{->}
%
\chemfig{(-[:210])(=[2]O)-[:330]O-[:30]-[:330]}
%
\+
%
\chemfig{(-[:210])(=[2]O)-[:330]OH}
\schemestop 
\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}    
    
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{center}
    \tabulinesep = ^ 4mm _ 4mm % border gap
    \begin{tabu} to 16cm {|X[cm]|}
        \hline
        \schemestart
        %
        \chemfig{(-[:210])(=[2]O)-[:330]OH}
        %
        \+
        %
        \chemfig{(-[:210])(=[2]O)-[:330]OH}
        %
        \arrow{->}
        %
        \chemfig{(-[:210])(=[2]O)-[:330]O-[:30](=[2]O)-[:330]}
        %
        \+
        %
        \chemfig{(-[:210])(=[2]O)-[:330]OH}
        \schemestop 
        \\
        \hline
    \end{tabu}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution that also uses `\arrow{0}[,0]` in order to vertically center all molecules, plus signs and arrows inside one reaction. I alo replaced the `tabu` based frame around the reaction schemes with a `tcolorbox` based approach. Since the acetic acid and acetic acid anhydride molecules in the second scheme look rather distorted due to different bond lengths, I added an alternative version that does not require manually adjusting each bond length:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white,colframe=black,sharp corners, halign=center, boxrule=\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]O-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75]-[:-30,0.75]OH}
    \arrow[,1.1,thick]
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]O-[:30,0.75]-[:-30,0.75]}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+ 
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]OH}
    \schemestop
\end{mybox}

\smallskip

\begin{mybox}
    \schemestart
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]OH}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]OH}
    \arrow[,1.5,thick]
    \chemfig{-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30]O-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+ 
    \chemfig{H_2O}
    \schemestop
\end{mybox}

\bigskip

\setchemfig{atom sep=2.5em}
\begin{mybox}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]O-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+
    \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]OH}
    \arrow[,1.1,thick]
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+ 
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}
    \schemestop
\end{mybox}

\smallskip

\begin{mybox}
    \schemestart
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}
    \arrow[,1.5,thick]
    \chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]O-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+ 
    \chemfig{H_2O}
    \schemestop
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```